# how to hide/show a div element based on selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons. I need to hide/show a div tag based on selected radio button

I select a radio button while loading the body (actually it's based on db value).

What I need as output is, I need to hide/show a div tag during the body load itself, but based on selected radio button.

here is the code i have tried.

```
<html>
       <head>
             <title>show-hide-div-on-click-using-jquery</title>

</head>
 <?php
 $r="r2";

echo "<body onload=\"calls('$r')\">";?>
     <center>
              <div style="padding:25px;width: 100px;">
                   <input id="id1" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="r1" />Radio1
                   <input id="id2" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="r2" />Radio2
              </div>
              <div align="center" style="padding:25px;width: 300px;">
                   <div id="div1">This is First (1st) division</div>
                   <div id="div2">This is Second (2nd) division</div>
              </div>
     </center>
     <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                 $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#id1').click(function () {
                       $('#div2').hide();
                       $('#div1').show();
                });
                $('#id2').click(function () {
                      $('#div1').hide();
                      $('#div2').show();
                 });
               });
                 function calls (r) {
                   if(r=="r1"){
    document.getElementById('id1').checked=true;
}
else{
    document.getElementById('id2').checked=true;
}
                 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But this code is not working as I expected. It hides/shows the div tag when I click a radio button.

I know I have to change the `click` by any other, since this function works only on clicking the radio button, but I don't know what to use instead of this `click`.

Comment: Maybe change() will help you? http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: No clue what you are asking, sorry.

Comment: Please take greater care when posting. This was riddled with typos that any spellcheck would have seen. This shows a lack of effort - why should we bother to read your question, understand it, and answer if you cannot be bothered to run a spellcheck?

Comment: @Filip change is working as similarly as click, no change in my output..Suggest me any other solution..

Comment: if you are setting the checked value using php then you can just do a check and use the same if statement to add a class to the div that will hide it depending on that condition

Comment: i love that, "suggest me another solution" we are not here to write code for you, just to help and show errors.

Comment: @user3784251 there is a huge difference between something giving you the correct output and something being coded properly. In this case, the `.change()` event is what you want to use. Not `.click()` because click will run every time that you click one of those buttons, as opposed to `.change()` which will run only when you need it to.

Comment: @BoristheSpider sorry for the mistakes i have done and thanks for denoting my mistakes,i will try to avoid those in future.Sorry, i am not good in english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `document.ready` call, you can immediately set the div that you need to be visible, based on the checked property of the radio button you've set in php. You can do this by checked the "checked" property via jQuery like so:

```
if ($('#id1').prop("checked") == true) {
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div1').show();
} else {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').show();
}
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gmm3j/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ID's and having 2 separate click events, you can delegate it to one event. as well as create a function to check which button is selected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    radioChecked();
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
        radioChecked();
    });

    function radioChecked(){
        if($('#id1').prop("checked") == true){
            $('#div1').show();
            $('#div2').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#div1').hide();
            $('#div2').show();
        }
    }
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gmm3j/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work (untested code):

```
$('[name=name_radio1]').change(function(){
    if ($('#id1').is(":checked") {
        $('#div2').hide();
        $('#div1').show();
    } else {
        $('#div1').hide();
        $('#div2').show();
    }
});
```

or even

```
$('[name=name_radio1]').change(function() {
    $('#div2, $div1').toggle();
});
```